# Images are not showing when files are deployed on live server from localhost

Tags: php, cakephp

hello I am storing images in this directory

```
APP/webroot/uploads/25/Trip/image25.png
```

when I type this url in browser

http://localhost/myproject/APP/webroot/uploads/25/Trip/image25.png

I can successfully see the image

after uploading the files onto live server the images doesn't load up when I type this url

http://www.mywebsite.com/myproject/APP/webroot/uploads/25/Trip/image25.png

it says

```
Error: APPController could not be found.

Error: Create the class APPController below in file: app/Controller/APPController.php

<?php
class APPController extends AppController {

}
```

my httaccess file is this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I even try to put index.php in the url but still no luck

http://www.mywebsite.com/myproject/index.php/APP/webroot/uploads/25/Trip/image25.png

I am developing an api in Cakephp for mobileapp so thats why I have to check the images like this first.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I guess your webserver is CASE SENSITIVE, try renaming APP to app and check again

Comment: have you tried with 'app' instead of 'APP ' ?

Comment: Indeed that is most likely the issue here. Note that http servers in the internet are usually operated based on Linux, so unixoid systems. Those systems use case sensitive file systems. So you have to make sure that the files names use the same character cases as the actual class names (lowercase and uppercase).

Comment: oh WAO Thank you very much. it was a case sensitive issue @Manikiran

Comment: @Indrajit No I didn't. but now its working after trying it. Thank you very much

Comment: @arkascha yes Thank you very much for your detail explanation